# How to batch rename files in a directory from a list of names in a text file

Tags: shell, powershell, batch-file, command-prompt

I'd like to use Power Shell or a batch file to rename several files in a folder based on a list in a text file. Essentially I want to append the file names with the author's last names (which I have stored in a separate text file).

E.g. Currently I have:

C:\myfiles

```
9-ART-2013.pdf
4-EGO-2013.pdf
2-ART-2013.pdf
```

My text file (in same order as files):

C:\myfiles

```
_Smith
_Jenkins
_McMaster
```

I want the files to be renamed as follows:

```
9-ART-2013_Smith.pdf
4-EGO-2013_Jenkins.pdf
2-ART-2013_McMaster.pdf
```

I've seen similar problems where people want to recursively rename files but they are always using a generic common appending element like adding an underscore or pre-pending with folder name, etc.

e.g. https://serverfault.com/questions/6268/easy-way-to-rename-all-files-in-a-directory-in-windows

Comment: How is the script supposed to determine which line in the text file corresponds to which filename?

Comment: Are the files to be sorted in the directory?  In which manner?  `Reverse-alphabetic` as per your list?

Comment: I was planning to just manually make sure the item order of my text file matches the folder order (assending). I have an excel file with a column for file_name and another column for the corresponding author_name.

Comment: I just realized that I framed the proposed solution incorrectly. the solution would be more robust to errors (matching "file name" to "author") to simply have a text file with an "OLD-Name | NEW-Name" structure.  9-ART-2013.pdf | 9-ART-2013_Smith.pdf  4-EGO-2013.pdf | 4-EGO-2013_Jenkins.pdf  2-ART-2013.pdf | 2-ART-2013_McMaster.pdf  Then I could just call each line from the text file using "For /f" and "Ren". I did try the solutions provided below and will enter comments below.

Comment: Permit me to reframe your problem.  It's much better to store the two columns in your excel spread sheet side by side in a single text file, perhaps separated by a comma.  It's then easy to import this csv file into an array of custom objects, and pipe this to a loop that calculates the new name for each item, and then does a Rename-Object to get the result.   From your previous comment, looks like you were headed in that direction.

Comment: Dumping a table into a CSV file is easy in Excel.

Answer (score 4):

In PowerShell it would be:

```
$names = Get-Content c\myfiles
Get-ChildItem C:\somedir\*.pdf | Sort -desc | 
    Foreach {$i=0} {Rename-Item $_ ($_.basename + $names[$i++] + $_.extension) -WhatIf}
```

If it looks like it will copy correctly, remove the `-WhatIf`.

Comment: I am new to PS. I tried entering the above directly at the prompt but got errors. "Get-Content : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'Get-ChildItem'. At line:1 char:21 + ...

Comment: The above was meant to be put on two lines.  If you want to enter it all on the same line put a `;` before `Get-ChildItem` to separate these two statements.

Answer (score 4):

Any of the above are likely workable solutions with just a little tweaking but the simplest thing to do was to simply create one text file with each row containing "the current filename"... a TAB... then "the filename I wanted".

```
9-ART-2013.pdf     9-ART-2013_Smith.pdf
4-EGO-2013.pdf     4-EGO-2013_Jenkins.pdf
2-ART-2013.pdf     2-ART-2013_McMaster.pdf
```

Then save the file as **rename_list.txt** and create a batch file with the following code.

```
for /F "tokens=1,2" %%a in (rename_list.txt) do ren "%%a" "%%b"
pause
```

You can delete the pause line once you get it tweaked and running correctly. Just copy the **rename_list.txt** and batch files to the folder with the files you want to rename and run the batch file. If you have a large folder with many files names you can get them in a text file by running a batch file with the following line.

```
dir /D > filename_scrapper_output.txt
```

It will create a text file **filename_scrapper_output.txt** that you can use to start your **rename_list.txt** file for above.

Comment: I don't fully understand how it works, but I edited to add `delims= `. Note that the space after = is supposed to be a tab space

Comment: Thanks, this helped me. I also added this line in the beginning: `CHCP 65001` because I wanted to use UTF-8 characters in the file names. Also added `delims= ` to use spaces in the file names: `for /F "tokens=1,2 delims= " %%a in (rename_list.txt) do ren "%%a" "%%b"`

Answer (score 1):

```
@ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
<Text.txt (
for /f "tokens=1*delims=_" %%a in ('dir /b /a-d /o-d *-*-*.pdf') do if "%%b"=="" (
    set "xand="
    set /p "xand="
    echo ren "%%~a" "%%~na!xand!%%~xa"
))
```

Comment: Um - just a couple of things: since the file-order appears to be reverse-alphabetical, how about a `/o-d` on that `DIR` and then a mask of `*-*-*.pdf may be useful. Finally, a `delims` of `_` with a `tokens=1,2` would allow `if "%%b"==""` to filter out the already-renamed files...

Comment: Hmm - personally, I'd put the `if "%%b==""` after the `DO` otherwise an input line would be eaten if `%%b` is NOT empty...

Comment: @Magoo when I ran this .bat it iterates through all the files but it appeared to be grabbing the old file name and renaming to the same old name i.e. not with the bit to be appended (the rows in the text file). As I mentioned above It may be less prone to error if the text file contained rows as "old-name | new-name" then I could just ren each row with the For /f.

Comment: Works perfectly for me with the latest code revision. OP's revised methodology would seem to make the debate academic.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to achieve the same thing:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Load the list of authors:
set i=0
for /F %%a in (myfiles.txt) do (
   set /A i+=1
   set "author[!i!]=%%a"
)

rem Do the rename:
set i=0
for /F %%a in ('dir /b *.pdf') do (
   set /A i+=1
   for %%i in (!i!) do ren "%%a" "%%~Na!author[%%i]!%%~Xa"
)
```

**EDIT**: *New method added*

If the list of names file have the "OLD-Name NEW-Name" structure, then the code is much simpler:

```
for /F "tokens=1,2" %%a in (myfiles.txt) do ren "%%a" "%%b"
```

Note that the names must be separated by a space.

Comment: Given my minimal CMD experience I wasn't able to hack this one to working even though it looks pretty straight forward. When I run the .bat the command window opens but just freezes.

Comment: @user1502159: It is possible that the cyclic rename cause problems. I slightly modified the code to avoid this point, and added a second method.

Answer (score 0):

Taking Endoro's and simplifying:

```
@ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
<texts.txt (
for /f "tokens=* delims=* " %%a in ('dir /b /a-d /o-d *-*-*.pdf') do (
set "xand="
set /p "xand="
ren "%%~a" "%%~na!xand!%%~xa"
))
```

Comment: by simplifying, you removed some security. Endoro's code ensures, that a file will not be renamed twice by accident (for example by running the batch twice)