# Rename files after a list of names

Tags: windows, batch-file, batch-processing

Let's say I have in a folder N avi video files and a text file, **names.txt**, with N lines.
I want to create a batch file that will rename all the video files as such:

- The first .avi file will take the name that is found on the first line of **names.txt**
- The second .avi file will take the name that is found on the second line of **names.txt**
- And so on... (the names will contain spaces)

I managed to write a script for parssing the **names.txt**

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1 delims=" %%a in (names.txt) do echo %%a
```

And here is the script thar parsses the .avi files

```
@echo off
for %%b in (*.avi) do echo %%~nb
```

How can I combine them so the passing will be done in parallel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I found what you need in this post: [How to batch rename files in a directory from a list of names in a text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20060429/how-to-batch-rename-files-in-a-directory-from-a-list-of-names-in-a-text-file)

I've tailored one of their solutions to try to answer your question...

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

rem Load the list of new filenames
set i=0
for /F "delims=" %%a in (names.txt) do (
   set /A i+=1
   set "newname[!i!]=%%a"
)
rem Do the rename:
set i=0
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /o:n *.avi') do (
   set /A i+=1
   for %%i in (!i!) do ren "%%a" "!newname[%%i]!"
)
```

I would be very careful with the order that you have the files listed. I recommend adding a sortorder to the "dir" command. 
[Windows DIR Command Documentation](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/dir.mspx?mfr=true)

Comment: I added the missing `delims=` to support long filenames, and added the sort by name switch in the lower for loop.

Comment: Thank you! I only modify one line and it worked like a charm.
    set "newname[!i!]=%%a.avi"